# While using Android Espresso automation tool getting some errors. Cannot find what is it exactly referring to

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

Below are the errors i am getting while building my application.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
```

FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/test/BuildConfig;
```

Can someone help me out with it ? is there anything that needs to be changed with build.gradle ?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sanket.loginapp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
}

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is my build.gradle. i did not find any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore these warnings.
`AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}`

For the build failure, it seems you reached the magic 65K method count. 
Change `multiDexEnabled` to `true` in `defaultConfig`

FYI:
I think its best practice to create debug build flavour in `buildTypes` as below. This way you can manage release apk size using ProGuard.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
     minifyEnabled true
     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    debug {
     multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```